# IV-9 Numitron Clock Flickering Issues

Tags: raspberry-pi, shift-register, nixie

Complete electronics novice here - any information at all is appreciated.

I'm attempting to rig up a numitron clock.
I've used:

- 4 x IV-9 Numitron tube
- 4 x TPIC6B595N shift register (chosen based on various forum posts)
- 1 x Raspberry Pi microcontroller

The shift registers follow into one another such that the output of the first becomes the input of the next and so on. It is not multiplexed.

I've tested it and the logic seems to be fine - each tube displays the correct digit. The issue is that the tubes refuse to stay lit - with each refresh some tubes become dimmer and then go out altogether. However, if I place my finger on an open wire, or even an exposed metal part on the raspberry pi, all tubes instantly work fine, with no flickering whatsoever. Adding to my confusion is that if I move my hand closer to the rig, without touching, the tubes react and become brighter. I want a clock, not a theremin.

As I said, I know close to nothing about electronics, so I'm sure that there is an obvious solution to this. I just can't for the life of me figure it out.

EDIT: If I touch my finger to **ground**, all digits are completely stable with no flickering at all. When I release my finger, the digits fade with each refresh until they go out. What does this mean?

Comment: Sounds like some charge is building up. Get a 10MegaOhm resistor, and holding one end, touch the other end to various places. Are all the pins of the ShiftRegister properly biased?

Comment: This sort of thing is often caused by a floating line that should not be - maybe an enable line or an input that is being driven by noise.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon that was it - an enable line (Pin 9 on the TPIC) wasn't set to ground... so simple! Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: For what I understand, the TPIC6B595N outputs on it's drain(s). But the IV-9 has max 4.5, maybe even lower for better durability. How did you lower that voltage? Putting a zenor diod or something on every output from the TPIC6B595N isn't very fun. How did you solve it? Thanks

Comment: @Jakkra I used 5V to power the TPIC6B595N, but set the 'main leg' (cathode?) of the IV-9 at 3.3V - when the shift register opens its drains each segment of the numitron only gets 3.3V. Hope that explains it! :)

Comment: Oh Okey, didn't know I could do that :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... The issue is that the tubes refuse to stay lit - with each refresh some tubes become dimmer and then go out altogether. However, if I place my finger on an open wire, or even an exposed metal part on the raspberry pi, all tubes instantly work fine, with no flickering whatsoever. Adding to my confusion is that if I move my hand closer to the rig, without touching, the tubes react and become brighter.

This sort of thing is often caused by a floating line that should not be - maybe an enable line or an input that is being driven by noise.